# Undefined reference when passing static member function as argument

Tags: c++, glfw

I'm attempting to set my glfw error and key callbacks to a function in class Game. When doing this, I get undefined references to the callback functions.

Here's what the relevant parts of the class looks like:

```
namespace TGE
{
    class Game
    {
        public:
            void init()
            {
                glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback)

                if(!glfwInit())
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

                window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Test", NULL, NULL);

                if(!window)
                {
                    glfwTerminate();
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
                glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

                start();
            }

            void start()
            {
                // Main loop stuff
            }

            static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
            {
                if(action == GLFW_PRESS)
                {
                    switch(key)
                    {
                        case GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE:
                            glfwSetWindowShouldCLose(window, GL_TRUE);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
            {
                fputs(description, stderr);
            }

        protected:
            GLFWwindow* window;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile I get

```
In function `TGE::Game::init()`:
undefined reference to `TGE::Game::error_callback(int, char const*)`
undefined reference to `TGE::Game::key_callback(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int, int)`
```

I have a feeling it may be because of the namespace, but I'm not sure how to get around that if it is.

EDIT: Moving everything out of the namespace results in the same error.

Comment: Have you tried moving the callback functions above the function in which they are used?

Comment: Seems you've sorted it (comment in answer below) but in case you are still suffering code blindness - you need a semi coloon after `glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback)`.

Comment: ^ That missing semicolon means that the code doesn't compile, which means it's not the real code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suspect what is going on here is that you defined the static member functions inside the class declarations, which makes them implicitly `inline`. Due to some compiler bug (or perhaps even standard-specified behavior?) the compiler is not instantiating the non-inline versions of these functions that actually have an address and a global symbol.

Whether that is correct behavior or not, **inline functions which are only used as callbacks via pointers is nonsense anyway.** So why it doesn't work is moot. Function calls that take place through pointers are not inlined.

You should only declare those functions in the class declaration, and then implement them somewhere.

```
// inside the class decl:
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);
```

and:

```
// inside some implementation file

#include "the_above_header.h"

// ...
void TGE::Game::key_callback(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int, int)
{
   // ...
}
```

Make sure that this file is compiled and linked in.

That writ, however, the following test program compiles and links for me with g++ 4.6.3.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Wrapping the class in a namespace makes no difference, by the way.
class test {
  int x[42];
public:
  test()
  {
    qsort(x, 42, sizeof x[0], compare);
  }
  static inline int compare(const void *, const void *)
  {
    return 0;
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  test t;
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The problem was actually that in the head for the game class I declared the functions key_callback and error_callback, but in the .cpp I wrote only static void key_callback not static void Game::key_callback. Since the functions were declared in the scope of Game the compiler looked there for them and the implementations were not in the scope of Game, thus causing the undefined reference.

Comment: Interestingly though, I did have to use -fpermissive when compiling, because gcc would not let me declare the member function to have static linkage. What exactly does that error mean? Why, if I can allow this in the compiler and everything works fine, should it even throw an error in the first place?

Comment: @user2941616 - You should not be passing C++ functions with C++ linkage, name mangling, etc., as a C function or function pointer, for use as a callback by a C library such as GLFW. It *might* work for a static method, as there's no object being passed, and the ABI *might* use the same calling conventions as for a C function - but that's not behaviour you can rely on.

Comment: @BrettHale It's not a behavior you can rely on for portability, but it's one of those things that can be verified to work on a given platform, like being able to convert between object pointers and (regular) function pointers.

Comment: @Kaz - the typical approach is to wrap the C++ static method call in a function with `extern "C"` linkage, and use that as the callback.

Comment: @BrettHale I know all that; it is not particularly relevant here. That issue won't be responsible for undefined references within a class to its own symbols, all in the same class declaration. The callbacks lacking the maximally portable `extern "C"` don't even have a chance to be used since the code doesn't link.

Comment: So it would be better practice for portability to do `#ifdef __cplusplus extern"C" { #endif CallBackFunctionHere #ifdef __cplusplus } #endif` Yes?

Comment: @user2941616 Why would you have `#ifdef __cplusplus` in C++ code with classes?

Answer (score -1):

I think its because your definition of `error_callback(...)` and `key_callback(...)` comes after the `init()` function, where both are used.

**EDIT:**
Ignore this, this cannot be the reason because it was a linker error (see comments below)

Comment: I didn't declare the functions Game::key_callback and Game::error_callback in the implementation. Stupid mistake. Guess that's what happens after a night of no sleep. That's working though now I have new errors to fix.

Comment: If you didn't declare them, how did the program get to the linking stage?